# making a jtable bigger to fit all data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I currently have a JTable inside a JscrollPane inside a JPanel. No matter what I set the size of either of those 3 elements, the table always shows up as the same size. The JPanel is in BorderLayout and I am packing the frame. the reason I want to do this is because some of the data in my columns doesn't fit without having to make other columns way too small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- override `table.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(int, int));`
- change `JPanel`s default LayoutManager `FlowLayout` (implemented in API) to `BorderLayout` or `GridLayout`

Comment: is there a way to not allow the dragging of columns to different slots?

Comment: yes its `JTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the JScroller preferred size because a table is often put inside of a scroller.

```
scrollerPhone.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
```